# Is there a standard file extension for block device image files

Tags: block-device

Block device image files are just a large contiguous set of blocks for the device they are emulating. I realize that file extensions are more for the user and that generally on Linux operating systems are not required.

I am curious if there is a standard extension, example **.img** as in lun1.img, used as a file based block device to be served as an iscsi target

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not aware of any de jure standard, but as far as de facto standards go, I think `.img` is as close as one exists.  However, as you note, they're unnecessary on Linux, so don't get too worked up about it.